# Is it possible to track the phone location without using GPS and show it on google map?

Tags: php, android, google-maps, web

I'm developing a website for my android anti theft application, and I added google maps for searching coordinates and routes. Here's my problem, i want to search the mobile phone without using GPS to get the coordinates, and show it on google maps to have an interaction within my website to my mobile phone.

Comment: What makes you think this should be possible?

Comment: an anti theft application without using gps ( read exact location ) truly defeats its purpose.. do rethink on your strategy

Comment: @android_hungry it uses GPS ofcourse, what i mean on my website.

Comment: can u think something on the lines of geolocation in HTML 5?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak do you know Cerberus anti theft app? They can view the Phone location on their website. Just like that.

Comment: @android_hungry -I think so, but Im not familiar on HTML5(geolocation) do you have a source on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to check is the GPS on:

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

If it is off, use network based location service.
It uses cell info (and on some phones uses wifi to get more precise info from a huge db where cellids and wifi ssids and coordinates are associated)

Maybe on rooted phones you can automatically turn on gps.

Comment: Thanks for the codes but Im done with my android app. Now, Im working with my website, do you have a source/related article with the network based location.

Comment: Network based Location: LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;   To display it in the browser I think you should also post the location.getAccuracy() value, and draw an overlay on the map, to show the accuracy. ( https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple ). You can post the values over internet, but you should think about sending sms when internet is not available. (and also listen for incomeing requests over sms)